# Overlapping Div Issue

Tags: html, css

Hi I'm attempting to make a web-comic website. My current issue is that I have
two Divs that are overlapping and I can't figure out what to do to fix the issue. The specific overlapping parts of my code are the content div and copyright container. In my CSS I have the content 20px away from the top of top-nav-bar . I'm trying to figure out how to keep this margin and make it so that the Content Div does not move over the Copyright Div. I have provided the HTML and what I hope is the relevant CSS. If you need more information please let me know I'll be more than happy to provide it.

```css
#content {
  width: 1100px;
  height: 1500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  top: 10px;
  background-color: #666;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10 px 0px rgba(12, 3, 25, 0.8);
  clear: both;
  display: inline-block;
}

.copyright-container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: ralative;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0px;
}

#wrapper {
  background-color: #333;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  min-height: 100%;
  background-image: url("images/bg-tileable.png");
  background-position: left-top;
  background-repeat: repeat;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  /*border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);*/
  border-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">

  <!--Site Image Banner -->
  <header>
    <img src="images/banner06.png" />
    <img class="logo" src="images/logo.png" />
    <!--
   <div class = "logo">
    <img src="images/logo.png"/>
   </div>
   -->
  </header>

  <!--Navigation bar below header Graphic -->
  <nav class="top-nav-bar">
    <ul class="nav-list">
      <li class='active'><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Comics</a></li>

      <li><a href="#">Comissions</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Tutorials</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <!-- Holds side panel outside links-->
  <div id="outside-links-container">
    <div class="title">
      <h3>
        <p class="title-text"> Other Works</p>
      </h3>
    </div>
    <nav class="outside-links">
      <!--Make Deviantart Logo and add <img> element -->
      <li>
        <a href="#" target="_blank" alt="Link my Deviantart"> <img src="images/da-logo02.png" /></a>
      </li>
      <!--Make Instagram Logo and add <img> element -->
      <li>
        <a href="#" target="_blank" alt="Link my Instagram"><img src="images/ig-logo.png" /></a>
        <li>
    </nav>
  </div>

  <!--Holds Comic Page and comic page Navigation -->
  <div id="content">
    <div class="title">
      <h1>
        <p class="title-text"> Omnibreed Page 01</p>
      </h1>
    </div>
    <div class="recent-post">
      <img class="comic-page" src="images/comic-pages/Chap01_Page 1_Low.png" />
    </div>

    <div class=" comic-navigation">
      <ul class="comic-nav-list">
        <li>
          <a href="#"><img src="images/arrow01.png" /></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#"><img src="images/arrow02.png" /></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#"><img src="images/archieve01.png" /></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#"><img src="images/arrow03.png" /></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#"><img src="images/arrow04.png" /></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="copyright-container">
  <p class="copyright"> &#169;Copyright 2017 Charles </p>
  <div>
```

Comment: It'll be a lot more helpful if you skim down your code to replicate the issue. Reading a wall of text (that's largely broken and irrelevant) makes a lot of people (like myself) uninterested in helping.

Comment: I honestly thought putting the bulk of the HTML might be relevant because I was unsure where I may have broken my code. Also I i'm trying to skim down the code  It's why I only put the most relevant CSS, at least as far as I know. So if your uninterested in helping I'm sorry but I'm not sure how to reduce the code further.  Maybe give some insight if you can get get away from your disinterest. Not trying to be disrespectful and unsure if you were so just looking for a bit a help. Kinda new at this if you couldn't tell.

Comment: Basically you could delete everything within your wrapper, then set a width and height to it and see what happens. But I'd assume that, from a glance at your css, `#content` is larger than 100% of the wrapper. For some reason, you've set a height and width to it.

Answer (score 0):

You misspelled relative

```
   .copyright-container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: ralative;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

Try fixing it, and see whether you get different  results

Comment: Thanks for catching that.I fixed that and the text is now above the div but the element is still overlapping. From what I can tell the element is actually moving outside of its containing div. The content div is outside of the wrapper div.

Comment: Try using absolute position for container. This will be relative to the wrapper